# Add personalized methods and attributes to CategoricalDtype

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to add personalized methods and attributes to Pandas `CategoricalDtype`? Should I use a class inheritance or something like [ExtensionDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype.html#pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype)?

For example:

```
vehicles = ["Plane", "Rocket", "Car", "Truck"]
vehicle_dtype = CategoricalDtype(categories=vehicles)
s = pd.Series(["Plane", "Plane", "Car"])
s = s.astype(vehicle_dtype)
```

Is there a solution to add methods and attributes to `vehicle_dtype` in order to do things like this?

```
s.cat.is_flying
[True, True, False]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer to this would be VERY long since you need to do 2 classes with a bunch of abstract methods declaration so I would advise you to take a look at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/cyberpandas IPArray is a good example on how you can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.cat` is a `pandas.core.arrays.categorical.CategoricalAccessor`. If you want `s.cat.is_flying` to work, you'll need to somehow tell the series to use a subclass accessor that you make instead of the default one. I don't know how to do that, though somebody might. You could instead monkeypatch your accessor on afterwards, but you'd have to do it every time you create a new series, so that seems very brittle and not maintainable. What you can do instead, though, is use a *separate* custom accessor instead of going through `.cat`. These actually aren't very difficult to define; see the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#registering-custom-accessors). Below is an example that should work for your use case:

```py
import pandas as pd

VehicleDtype = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(["Plane", "Rocket", "Car", "Truck"])

@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor("vehicle")
class VehicleAccessor:
    def __init__(self, series):
        self._validate(series)
        self._series = series

    @staticmethod
    def _validate(series):
        if not isinstance(series.dtype, CategoricalDtype) or series.dtype != VehicleDtype:
            raise TypeError("Must be VehicleDtype.")

    @property
    def is_flying(self):
        return (self._series == "Plane") | (self._series == "Rocket")

s = pd.Series(["Plane", "Plane", "Car"])
s = s.astype(VehicleDtype)

s
# 0    Plane
# 1    Plane
# 2      Car
# dtype: category
# Categories (4, object): [Plane, Rocket, Car, Truck]

s.vehicle.is_flying
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2    False
# dtype: bool
```

For series that aren't of the right type, they'll only throw an error if they try to use the `.vehicle` accessor:

```
s2 = pd.Series(list("abcde"))  # works fine
s2.vehicle # TypeError: Must be VehicleDtype.
```

Note, though, that doing `dir(s2)` will throw this same error.

There is a similar function to register accessors for dataframes.

Comment: Thank you !! That perfectly fits my need !